# I am getting fractional artifacts (pieces of metal) instead of whole ones. It seems that the edges are not continuous but they are

Tags: python, opencv, object-detection, contour, canny-operator

My goal is to detect objects placed on a white surface. From there, count how many there are and calculate the area of each one.

It seems that this algorithm is detecting its edge but counting it as multiple objects.

original picture

[image]

picture after edge detection

[image]

part of the picture with problems

[image]

results

[image]

In short, I am using "canny" and "connected components" and I am getting fractional objects instead just a whole object.

Comment: You'll probably have a better time with `findContours` than manual edge detection. https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code should do the job, you might need to tweak minItemArea and maxItemArea to filter objects.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

rgb = cv2.imread('/path/to/your/image/items_0001.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(rgb, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

imh, imw = gray.shape

th = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray,255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV,21,5)

contours, hier = cv2.findContours(th.copy(),cv2.RETR_CCOMP,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

out_img = rgb.copy()
minItemArea = 50
maxItemArea = 4000

for i in range(len(contours)):
    if hier[0][i][3] != -1:
        continue
        
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(contours[i])
    if minItemArea < w*h < maxItemArea:
        cv2.drawContours(out_img, [contours[i]], -1, 255, 1)

plt.imshow(out_img)
```

[image: Contours of Items]

Comment: Thank you for your comments. It worked better with that than with edge detection.